# Create multiple table with python in Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I've search trought a lot a internet site and I cannot find the answer.
I try to create 4 tables in my SQLite database with this code:

```
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(current_directory, 'fidouda.db'))
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Clients (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Prenom, Nom, Adresse, Email, Telephone, Genre, Factures, Fidelite);''')
            c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Factures (ID, Client, Items, Date, Prix, Promotion, Sous-total, Total, Payer, Rpayer);''')
            c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Inventaire (Stock, Nom, Prix);''')
            c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Rabais (Nom, Pourcentage);''')
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            if conn:
                conn.close()
                return os.path.join(current_directory, fname)
```

The problem is that only the first table are created. How can I create all my table ?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Except for the first column in the first table, none of these columns have data types, which I thought was required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this code, it will output this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "-": syntax error
```

Specifically, the hyphen in the column `Sous-total`, you can either surround the column name in quotes, like this:

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Factures (ID, Client, Items, Date, Prix, Promotion, 'Sous-total', Total, Payer, Rpayer);''')
```

Or pick another column name that won't cause problems.

Comment: That work … I dont know why but when I run this, I dont get error … Maybe "hidden" by other thing in my script. I feel a little bit dumb …. Thanks a lot